# Python code has no error but it does not run or output anything

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I copied a piece of code online. When I run it, it shows no error, but it did not output anything. Can anyone help me with this? I am new to python. I was running it in Spyder. Is there any way to see where the problems are? ... I tried some other script in this environment and they work fine.
Here is the script:

```
from numpy import array , matrix , ones , sum , prod

class Vertex():
    def __init__ (self,compat):
        self.compat = compat
        compat = []
        neighbors = [] # list of numbers
        messageout = [] # list of outgoing messages
        messagein = [] # list of incoming messages from neighbors

    def marginal (self): 
        print('hello')
        a = prod(self.messagein.values(), 0)
        a = self.compat * a
        return a /( sum ( a ))

def compat(i,j):
    if i == j:
        return 1.0
    else:
        return 0.5

def f(x):
# defines the singleton potential functions
    if x % 2 == 0:
        return array ([0.7 ,0.3])
    else:
        return array ([0.1 ,0.9])

class myV():
    V = [(Vertex(f(x))) for x in range(6)]
    V[0].neighbors =[1 ,2]; V[1].neighbors =[0 ,3 ,4];
    V[2].neighbors =[0 ,5]; V[3].neighbors =[1];
    V[4].neighbors =[1]; V[5].neighbors =[2];
    for i in range (6):
        for j in V [i].neighbors :
            V [i].messageout = \
                dict ([(x , array ([1 ,1])) \
                       for x in V[i].neighbors])
            V [i].messagein = \
                dict ([(x , array ([1 ,1])) \
                       for x in V [i].neighbors])

    def broadcast(self):
        for i in range(6):
            for j in self . V [i]. neighbors :
                self . V [i]. messageout [j]= array ([0 ,0])
                for my_loop in range (2):
                    self.V[i].messageout[j] = \
                    ( self.V[i].messageout [j] +
                    self.V[i].compat[my_loop] *
                    array ([compat(my_loop ,0) ,
                        compat(my_loop,1)]) *
                    prod([self.V [ i ].messagein[x][ my_loop ]
                        for x in self.V[i].neighbors
                        if x != j ]))

    def receive(self):
        for i in range(6):
            for j in self.V[i].neighbors :
                self.V[i].messagein[j] = self.V [j].messageout [i]

def main():
    a = myV()
    for k in range(6):
        a . broadcast()
        a . receive()

    for k in range(6):
        print('hello')
        print('Marginal for node', k , 'is ', a.V[k].marginal())

if __name__ == '__main__ ':
    print('hello')
    main()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Change `if __name__ == '__main__ ':` to be `if __name__ == '__main__':`. There is a whitespace character at the end of `'__main__'` that shouldn't be there. Then you can have fun with the next issue: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'dict_values'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code works well with python2.7 and changing your code with (removed extra whitespace):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('hello')
    main()
```

For these kind of problems don't hesitate to use a debugger. PyCharm for example https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/

After that :

```
hello
hello
hello
('Marginal for node', 0, 'is ', array([0.59098405, 0.40901595]))
hello
hello
('Marginal for node', 1, 'is ', array([0.10161794, 0.89838206]))
hello
hello
('Marginal for node', 2, 'is ', array([0.59622558, 0.40377442]))
hello
hello
('Marginal for node', 3, 'is ', array([0.06575926, 0.93424074]))
hello
hello
('Marginal for node', 4, 'is ', array([0.56742955, 0.43257045]))
hello
hello
('Marginal for node', 5, 'is ', array([0.12965594, 0.87034406]))
```